# popViewControllerAnimated: called on UINavigationController while an existing transition or presentation is occurring

Tags: ios, swift, popviewcontroller

I have a tableview, and as soon as anyone presses a cell, the viewcontroller should pop. This is the code for my **tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)** method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //previously written code
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Everything works fine, except for one case: as soon as view loaded, i try to press on any cell immediately. In that situation **popViewController** isn't executed and i get this error:

> popViewControllerAnimated: called on UINavigationController while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

I know, this question appeared before on StackOverflow, but i didn't find any other solution than:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + //time) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

It works great, but i don't need a delay when pressing on tableview cell. As soon as presentation is over, **popViewController** works as required and delay in execution isn't needed.

Is there another way to make this happen? Or somehow get a notification, when the transition is ready, so i can pop afterwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `UIViewController`'s `transitionCoordinator`.

Its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1619294-transitioncoordinator) says:

> When a presentation or dismissal is in progress, this method returns the transition coordinator object associated with that transition. If there is no in-progress transition associated with the current view controller, UIKit checks the view controller’s ancestors for a transition coordinator object and returns that object if it exists. You can use this object to create additional animations and synchronize them with the transition animations.

```
let completion = {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

guard let coordinator = transitionCoordinator else {
    completion()
    return
}

coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
    completion()
}
```